# Clang Static Analyzis check Obj C code

Tags: objective-c, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying to make a source code which I can check by Clang Static Analyzer.

I am fully newbie in Obj C so I don't know how can I use these small code parts.

Here is the checkers list:
http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html#osx_checkers

osx.cocoa.AtSync (ObjC):

```
void test(id x) {
  if (!x)
    @synchronized(x) {} // warn: nil value used as mutex
}
```

I just need a 5-10 lines of code which I can test. I don't want to someone make codes for all checker, I just need an example for one.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a very broad question.  Do you expect someone to provide code for each checked issue?

Comment: No no, I hope someone can make a code for one checker, just in 5-10 lines. Maybe a hello world which contains this part: 
void test(id x) {
  if (!x)
    @synchronized(x) {} // warn: nil value used as mutex
}
I will edit my question.